# How to combine `lshw` and `grep` command inside `execv` in C?

Tags: c, grep, exec, pipeline

Here is a C program which operates finding specific properties like CPU bus info by consecutive calls of `lshw` (to access total hardware list with respective properties) and `grep` (to select just a relevant point among `lshw` results):

```
char *strCombine(char *str1, char *str2, int n)
{
    int i = strlen(str2);
    int j = 0;
    if((str2 = (char *) realloc(str2, (i + n + 1))) == NULL)
        perror(0);
    while(j < n && str1[j])
    {
        str2[i] = str1[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    str2[i] = 0;
    return (str2);
}

int main() 
{
    pid_t parent;
    char buf[1000] = {0};
    char *str;
    char *argv[6] = {"/usr/bin/lshw", "-C", "CPU", "|", "grep", "bus info"};       
    int fd[2];
    int ret;

    if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        return -1;
    }
    parent = fork();
    if(parent == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        while((ret = read(fd[0], buf, 1000)))
            str = strCombine(buf, str, ret);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        execv(argv[0], argv);            
        close(fd[1]);
        wait(0);
    }
    wait(0);
    printf("%s", str);


    return 0;
}
```

In this code `grep` is expected to follow `lshw` since both go executed by invoking `execv`. However, this pipeline doesn't work because `lshw` usage reference gets printed out in terminal (running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) instead of `bus info` needed originally. What makes this program failed to show just info that matters and what way must I try to set up pipeline?

Comment: Just call `system()` instead?

Comment: If you aren't going to do the pipe-work yourself, you should probably use `popen()` to run your command pipeline.  Using `"|"` as an argument to `execv()` will be passed as another string to the command, `lshw`; it will not be interpreted as shell would interpret it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, fine solution, just what I was looking for. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar is not a parameter you use to separate commands, as the `execve(2)` system call will load a program into the virtual space of **one process** only.  You need to create two processes, one per command you want to execute, and communicate them so input from one goes to output from the other.  I think also you'll be interested in the output of the last command, so you need to do two redirections (one from the first command to the second, and one from the output of the second command to a pipe descriptor), two forks, and two exec's in order to do this.

First the good news, you can do all this stuff with a simple call to `popen(3)` without the nitty gritties of making forks and execs while redirecting i/o from individual commands.  Just use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char *cmd = "/usr/bin/lshw -C CPU | grep 'bus info'";
        int n = 0;
        char line[1000];

        /* f will be associated to the output of the pipeline, so you can read from it.
         * this is stated by the "r" of the second parameter */
        FILE *f = popen(cmd, "r");
        if (!f) {
                perror(cmd);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* I read, line by line, and process the output,
         * printing each line with some format string, but
         * you are free here. */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {
                char *l = strtok(line, "\n");
                if (!l) continue;
                printf("line %d: [%s]\n", ++n, l);
        }

        /* once finished, you need to pclose(3) it.  This
         * makes program to wait(2) for child to finish and
         * closing descriptor */
        pclose(f);
}
```

If you need to mount such a pipeline you'll end having to
redirections from first command to second, from second to
parent process, and fork/exec both processes yourself.

In this approach, you handle a subshell to do the piping
and redirection work for you, and just you get a `FILE *` descriptor to read upon.

(if I find some time, I'll show you a full example of a chain of N commands with redirections to pipe them, but I cannot promise, as I have to write the code)

## NOTE

`fork()` returns the pid of the child process to the parent, and `0` to the child process itself.  I don't understand why you have a variable named `parent` where you store the value received from `fork()`.  If it is nonzero (and non-negative) it represents the pid of a child process.  You need two, as you need two processes.  In the example I post, you create three processes (you ask a subshell to mount the pipeline for you, so you have a subshell you instruct to create two more processes, to execute your command)  If you had to mount all this paraphernalia, you'd also to `wait(2)` for the children to finish (this is done in `pclose(3)` call)

I have a little program to spawn a process (only one) repeatedly, while overprinting its output in the same place.  I use it as some kind of `htop` program when I try to see e.g. the output of `ls -l`  (showing a file growing as it is being filled) or the output of `df` command.  It starts the program, makes one fork, redirects the output of it to a pipe and gets the output of the command to count the number of lines output (to emit an escape sequence to put the cursor on top of the listing, and to emit a *clear to the end of line* after each output line, so shorter lines dont get blurred by longer ones.  It shows you how to deal with forks and exec system calls, and you can use as example on how to do the things the brave way.  But having `popen(3)` I think is the solution to your problem.  If you want to have a look to my `cont` program, just  find it [here](https://github.com/mojadita/cont).